# How to typecast in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add total of my data:

```
[{"sector": "Basic drinking water supply and basic sanitation", "budget": 558733.7, "no": 8},
{"sector": "Culture and recreation", "budget": 1550000.0, "no": 2},
{"sector": "Roads", "budget": 1221142.04, "no": 4},
{"sector": "Agriculture", "budget": "", "no": 1},
{"sector": "Health", "budget": "", "no": 4},
{"sector": "Education", "budget": 473379.58, "no": 6},
{"sector": "Energy generation &amp; supply", "budget": 584624.55, "no": 1},
{"sector": "Agricultural water resources", "budget": 40000.0, "no": 1}]
```

so my code goes like this:

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
data[i]["budget"]= +data[i]["budget"];
console.log(+data[i]["budget"]);
end_val+= data[i]["budget"];
console.log(end_val);
}
```

but the output is concatenation of string. Why does `javascript` not typecast my values to integer? i tried `parseInt()` too.

Comment: Because `""+123 == "123"`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and It's working I think.

Comment: it's working because when you'll say (+"") it will return 0.

Comment: Well, what's `end_val` to begin with? If `end_val` is declared as a string, it will stay a string in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sum all the budget right?

You need to cast using `parseFloat` and check whether the parsed value is a number or not using `isNaN`.

```
var data = [
    {"sector": "Basic drinking water supply and basic sanitation", "budget": 558733.7, "no": 8},
    {"sector": "Culture and recreation", "budget": 1550000.0, "no": 2},
    {"sector": "Roads", "budget": 1221142.04, "no": 4},
    {"sector": "Agriculture", "budget": "", "no": 1},
    {"sector": "Health", "budget": "", "no": 4},
    {"sector": "Education", "budget": 473379.58, "no": 6},
    {"sector": "Energy generation &amp; supply", "budget": 584624.55, "no": 1},
    {"sector": "Agricultural water resources", "budget": 40000.0, "no": 1}
];

var sum = 0;
for (i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    var val = parseFloat(data[i]["budget"]);
    sum += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
}
console.log(sum);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R69MG/)

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should sum everything up easily

```
var sum = data.reduce(function(sum, row) {
  return sum += Number(row.budget);
}, 0);
```

As for the string issue, that's happing because some rows have `{budget: ""}`. When a `string` is added to a `float` in JavaScript, it becomes a string. Additional "additions" will be string concatenations.

**Note:** this requires ECMAScript `>= 5`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize end_val variable to 0. Check whether both the operands are of type Number when you use increment operator for number addition.

```
var end_val = 0;
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){        
     end_val+= parseFloat(data[i]["budget"]);
     console.log(end_val);
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation whenever possible when posting code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you use :---> Typecast.js

```
var sum = 0;
for (i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    var val = type.num.to(data[i]["budget"]);
    sum += type.nan(val) ? 0 : val;//---->HERE You dont even need to do this validation 
}
console.log(sum);
```

[Typecast.js--->LINK:](http://www.typecastjs.org/)

Typecast is distributed under the MIT licence

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your values are not integers.

Try using `parseFloat()`

Hope this helps.